# Testing threshold cointegration in vector error-correction models

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, cointegration, multivariate-regression, threshold

In Hansen and Seo's paper on [Testing two regime threshold cointegration in VECM](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/joe_02.pdf) (J. Econometrics, 2002; 110:293), the authors proposed a test based on Lagrange Multiplier for testing treshold in model. However, suddenly the model denotes heteroskedasticity.
Why the model denote heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the paper?  There is no way anyone can helpou without seeing the paper.

Comment: This https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:X4CvNY6JV8gJ:www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/joe_02.pdf+testing+threshold+cointegration&hl=en&gl=id&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi98PWX1spu2uoNsblIPCmJEZvLqhboUSfXkG2S4HoNxnxihMCiPSvFyJRon7gDmoeUvx5cjZgx7GEAyjnDNZuFAulWuap1Y_T6kh7Sh_DdY3HUCTUiwjXAQGHE5cbWcXzZ-RSc&sig=AHIEtbQRlio2_1CicJrHf_ZcSHcIw8MYcg

Comment: please help me, my problem in section 3.1, why use heteroskedasticity?

Comment: Thanks I will take a look and will help if I can.  But this may not be my area of expertise.

Comment: I have been busy but I think I will have time to read this today.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Hansen and Seo use a heteroskedasticity-robust covariance matrix for the LM statistic testing for threshold effect. Moreover, they use a regime-specifc version of it, where they estimate the robust covariance matrix for each regime, then add it (see equation 12).

Why do they do this? I would rather ask the opposite: why not? In econometrics, it is usually considered a good thing to obtain a heteroskedasticity-robust test, as this means the test will not only work with iid errors, but also for a larger class of errors. So this should only be considered an improvement of the test, and does not change the meaning of the test itself (still testing for threshold effects!).

But in case you are not happy with this, you simply have to change the V_1, V_2 matrices to the standard homoskedastic covariance matrix. Note this might be tricky as usual implementations (like the one from the author, or contained in R package tsDyn) use a different expression of the same LM test.